# How do I import package from Java project to OSGi Bundle project?

Tags: import, osgi, bundle

I have a big Java EE application and a simple OSGi Bundle application. I need to use Java classes from this Java EE application in my bundle. How can I do this?

I tried to include the Java EE app in the Java Build Path of my Bundle as "required project", but it is not applicable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need the Java EE classes just as a library, you can package them as a jar inside your bundle and use the Bundle-ClassPath directive.

Comment: Bundle-Classpath only works in OSGi which makes it not work when you use the jar in other envs.

Answer (score 0):

Look at bndtools (or the maven bundle plugin). With bnd it is trivial to include classes from other projects.

So in bndtools you just add the Java EE app on your buildpath and then you use the Private-Package directive with the package names that you want included in your bundle, wildcards are allowed.

You could also make a project that is a bundle that contains all your shared classes. This bundle is then added to the Java EE app.